# How to make web scraping faster using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I created this code to get data from this site "https://www.oddsmath.com/football/italy/serie-a-1315/2023-02-26/ac-milan-vs-atalanta-4052172/#DC", but the problem is that it takes too much time (about 1 minute), and I have to repeat the same procedure for many other links.
is there a way to do it faster?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
chromeOptions.add_argument("ignore-certificate-errors")
chromeOptions.add_argument('--headless=chrome')
wbe = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/paolopiceni/Desktop/scraping/chromedriver', options=chromeOptions)
wbe.get('https://www.oddsmath.com/football/italy/serie-a-1315/2023-02-26/ac-milan-vs-atalanta-4052172/#DC')
rows = wbe.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#table-odds-cat-1 > tbody > tr')
for idx,row in enumerate(rows):
    tooltip_1X = row.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td[class*=odds-1X] > .tooltip .odd-value')
    sbobet1X= row.text
    if sbobet1X.__contains__("SBOBET"):
        numero_quote1X=int(len(tooltip_1X))
        ultima_quota1X=float(tooltip_1X[0].get_attribute('innerText'))
        prima_quota1X=float(tooltip_1X[numero_quote1X-1].get_attribute('innerText'))
        print(prima_quota1X, ultima_quota1X)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the search feature in the Network Tab to find where the data is coming from.

[image]

In this case it's coming from:

```
https://www.oddsmath.com/api/v1/live-odds.json/?event_id=4052172&cat_id=1&include_exchanges=1&language=en&country_code=IT
```

Note the **event_id=4052172** is the id from the original URL which you need to provide.

You can fetch this data directly without Selenium:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://www.oddsmath.com/api/v1/live-odds.json/?event_id=4052172&cat_id=1&include_exchanges=1&language=en&country_code=IT')
>>> r.json()['data']['SBOBET']
{'x-id': 8,
 'updated': '2023-05-19T11:47:21',
 'updating': True,
 'liveBetting': False,
 'active': True,
 'live': {'uid': '0084e1f63',
  'updated': '2023-02-26 19:47:13',
  '1X': 1.34,
  '12': 1.34,
  'X2': 1.61},
 'history': [{'
  ...
```